# How do I set a cooldown for command 'apply' on the trigger of the command 'resign'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I am making an economy system in my bot "Swayde". Now, I have made an `apply` command via which you can apply for a job and unlock the `work` command. Then I added a command called `resign` via which you can set your job to **None**. Now I want to make it as such that when you resign, you need to wait another 12 hours use the `apply` command again. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is adding a commands check. This makes it so that the command is activated for the author only if he passes the check.

An example of this would be:

```py
async def is_owner(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id == 316026178463072268

@bot.command(name='eval')
@commands.check(is_owner)
async def _eval(ctx, *, code):
    """A bad example of an eval command"""
    await ctx.send(eval(code))
```

The check function **`is_owner`** returns `True` or `False`. You can make your own check function that could check your database for the users profile and see if the user has applied or not.